# Make each column of a table have same width

Tags: tables, arrays

I have a table as follows:

```
  &$\begin{array}{c|cc|cc}
    & x & \multicolumn{1}{c}{y} & i & 0 \\ \hline
    x & 0 & \multicolumn{1}{c}{} & -49 &  \\
    y & & \multicolumn{1}{c}{0} &  &  \\ \cline{4-5}
    i & 49 & & 0 &-2\\ 
    0 & &  & 2 & 0
  \end{array}$
```

Is there a way to make each column have same width?

Comment: Please read the documentation of `array`.

Comment: Sorry, have not found anything which helps...

Comment: This question needs considerable clarification. Ideally you should provide us with a minimum complete document that illustrates what you have so far, and, perhaps, a diagram of what you're trying to achieve. All I get from the code you supply is a jumble.

Comment: [Documentation of array](http://ctan.org/pkg/array) Table 1 -- column type `p{width}`

Comment: @MarcoDaniel But you suppose that the correct width is known in advance, which needn't be the case. The question brings some new aspects that cannot be simply solved by `p` column specification.

Comment: have you looked at the `tabularx` documentation?

Comment: @tohecz: Of course. Based on the question he wants the same width in each column. Not more ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For fixed-column width with known column entries, I would suggest using `\settowidth{<length register>}{<stuff>}` to extract the width of the widest element in your `array`. Alternatively, the [`calc` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/calc) provides `\widthof{<stuff>}` that provides a similar work-around:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}% http://ctan.org/pkg/array
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash$}p{#1}<{$}}

\begin{document}

\newlength{\mycolwd}% array column width
\settowidth{\mycolwd}{$-49$}% "width" of $-49$; largest element in array
\[
  \begin{array}{C{\mycolwd}*{4}{|C{\mycolwd}}}
      &  x & \multicolumn{1}{c}{y} &   i &  0 \\ \hline
    x &  0 & \multicolumn{1}{c}{}  & -49 &    \\
    y &    & \multicolumn{1}{c}{0} &     &    \\ \cline{4-5}
    i & 49 &   &   0 & -2 \\ 
    0 &    &   &   2 &  0
  \end{array}
\]

\end{document}
```

For example, using `calc`, one could use

```
  \begin{array}{C{\widthof{$-49$}}*{4}{|C{\widthof{$-49$}}}}
```

Note the use of `*{<num>}{<col spec>}` which repeats `<col spec>` a total of `<num>` times. It improves consistency and ease of updating.

Answer (score 10):

It's quite complicated to get the same width of all columns of an alignment without the user telling TeX what the desired column width  or the preferred total width of the alignment is.

It's indeed possible by typesetting the alignment twice, the first one for gathering all the cells and measuring them. However, for a simple matrix as yours, it's probably easier to state a size, guessing at the widest entry:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash$}p{#1}<{$}}

\begin{document}

$\begin{array}{C{1.8em}|C{1.8em}C{1.8em}|C{1.8em}C{1.8em}}
    & x & \multicolumn{1}{c}{y} & i & 0 \\ \hline
    x & 0 & \multicolumn{1}{c}{} & -49 &  \\
    y & & \multicolumn{1}{c}{0} &  &  \\ \cline{4-5}
    i & 49 & & 0 &-2\\ 
    0 & &  & 2 & 0
  \end{array}$

\end{document}
```

Just remember that, approximately, 1em is as wide as a capital M. As long as one entry in a column is not `\multicolumn`, you can use `c` for the argument of `\multicolumn`, because the effect will be exactly the same.

Answer (score 2):

With `{NiceArray}` of `nicematrix`, you have a key `columns-width`. If that key is used with the value `auto`, all the columns of the array will have the same width, equal to the width of the widest cell of the array.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}

$\begin{NiceArray}{c|cccc}[columns-width=auto]
  & x  & y & i   & 0  \\ \Hline
x & 0  &   & -49 &    \\
y &    & 0 &     &    \\ 
i & 49 &   & \Block[borders={left,top}]{2-2}{}
             0   & -2 \\ 
0 &    &   & 2   & 0
\end{NiceArray}$

\end{document}
```

[image: Output of the above code]